# Help on recovering wallet through brute force or from extension data (Bounty on recovery)

Tags: metamask, private-key, recovery

I know 10 of 64 characters (hex) of my ethereum private key unencrypted and their positions. I also know the corresponding wallet address.

Is a brute-force possible? What I am thinking of is generating addresses from private keys in ascending order until the address matches mine.
Is there a more efficient method since I know the address?

How long does an average PC take to generate addresses for say 100 private keys?

I had imported the unencrypted private key once to Metamask (Chrome) and removed the extension. Is it possible to recover the private key from data recovered from C:\Users\ Username \AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data ? I remember the password used while setting it up (before importing) if it is of use.

I will give bounty if your help contributes to recovering my wallet.

Please help!

Comment: To be clear, I am serious about this. I want to estimate the costs to brute force it and decide whether or not to do it.

Answer (score -4):

I have software and hardware at my disposal. I can help. But I didn't quite understand what you have.How many words will you take from the seed phrase?

https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=5203140.msg55733352#msg55733352

Contact me:  wokfjfom@10mail.org